# CannotAcquireLockException/DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've got the following scenario:

1. A table with two columns, internal and external id
2. Requests to my service always have the external id and if no internal id is set yet (stateless), the service is called and tries to find a matching internal id.
3. If an entry is found, the internal id is set in the entity.
4. If no entry an ID-Service is called that provides a new unique ID (framework solution, can't really touch that) and the new entry will be persisted.

If I run the test chain, I randomly get CannotAcquireLockExceptions and DuplicateKeyExceptions from hibernate. There seems to be a deadlock and the scenario that two transactions are both looking for an entry and not finding it and crashing when the second transaction tries to persist a new entry for the unique key external id.

I'm kinda lost on how to approach this problem. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

/Edit: Some code to show what I do:

`Integer idInt = mapExtToInt(idExt); // select`

`if (idInt == null) {`

```
    idInt = callIdService(); // get id from id service

    createIntExtMapping(idInt, idExt); // save
```

`}`

There can be several tests that use the same idExt of course.

/Edit2: I've managed to make it occur less often, but the problem is still there. I've added a flush after each transaction (those with propagation=REQUIRES_NEW) before the next transaction in this test class is executed. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some source code?

Comment: Code example added

Comment: That code example is absolutely useless. How should we tell if/where synchronization goes wrong from those lines?

Comment: I think it's a design problem. The transaction as a whole is much larger and too much to share.